# Trouble using two Scanners for different input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

When using `Scanner` to read from standard input, the newline one enters apart from what's intended to be read is not consumed, causing trouble with subsequent inputs. This can be fixed using something like `exampleScanner.nextLine()`. However I'm trying to use two different scanners as below and am not able to fix the problem. I know there are a ton of questions and answers related to this type of problem with `Scanner` but I still can't seem to find an answer to my particular problem. Is my problem fixable or do I have to make do with one `Scanner`? Here's some code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class ScannerTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    char sym = ' ';
    int x = 0;

    /* scan for char (string) */
    Scanner scanForSym = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a symbol: ");
    try {
      sym = scanForSym.next().charAt(0);
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      System.err.println("Failed to read sym: "+e.getMessage());
    }
    scanForSym.nextLine(); // makes no diff when using different Scanner
    scanForSym.close();

    /* scan for int with different scanner */
    Scanner scanForX = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("\nEnter an integer: ");
    try {
      x = scanForX.nextInt();
      //x = scanForSym.next(); // this works fine (comment out the close above)
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      System.err.println("Failed to read x: "+e.getMessage());
    }
    scanForX.close();

    System.out.println("sym: "+sym);
    System.out.println("x: "+x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `nextLine()` instead of `next()`.  The same Scanner can be used to get the int.

Comment: I'm aware of that, as I indicated. The question is whether the above can be resolved using two scanners, not if the above could be done with a single scanner.

Answer (score 1):

Error is associated with this line:

```
scanForSym.close();
```

which closes the System.in InputStream.  So then this call

```
x = scanForX.nextInt();
```

throws an IOException since `scanForX` is trying to read from an already closed InputStream.

Try moving

```
scanForSym.close();
```

somewhere below

```
x = scanForX.nextInt();
```

Although (restating from the comments) it's not clear why you want to use multiple Scanner instances when they're both associated with `System.in`.